Is an almost-everywhere-solution also a weak solution?
Specifically, I have a second order elliptic equation $Lu=f$ where $f$ and the coefficients of $L$ are smooth. If $u$ is weakly differentiable and $Lu=f$ holds for almost everywhere in the domain of $u$, then can we obtain that $u$ is a weak solution of the equation $Lu=f$?
I would be grateful if anyone can help me!

Might depend on $L$ and the domain $\Omega$, but usually you just multiply by a test function and integrate by parts. So yes

@HyperbolicPDEfriend For my situation, $L$ is $\triangle$ and $\Omega$ is a compact $2$-manifold such as $\mathbb{S}^2$. This is true for this case right? Thanks !

Should be true, yes. You should check yourself if the integration by parts work out, and there might be boundary terms.

No. Let $n=1$, $\Omega=(-1,1)$, and $u(x)=\vert x \vert$. Then $u\in H^1((-1,1))$ with $$u’(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, &\text{if }x<0\\ 1,&\text{if }x>0
\end{cases} $$and $$u’’=0 \qquad \text{a.e. in }(-1,1). $$ However, if $v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, then \begin{align*}
 \int_{-1}^1u’v’ \, dx &=  -\int_{-1}^0v’ \, dx+  \int_0^1v’ \, dx\\
&=-2v’(0)
\end{align*} which is non-zero in general.

If there is an additional condition that $\Omega$ is a compact surface (without boundary) and $n=2$, can things be better? Thanks anyway!

No, I don't think so. The problem is inherently local (in the above counter-example the fact $\Omega=(-1,1)$ is somewhat irrelevant - the problem is at a single point $x=0$), so on a manifold, you just take charts and locally construct a counter-example
